# I want to add one array key and value with another array values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add one array key and value with another array's value.

If I have arrays as follow:

```
Array ( [6] => 12 [8] => 9 [10] => 11 )

Array ( [6] => 70 [8] => 10 [9] => 35 [10] => 25 [11] => 25 [12] => 2 )
```

For example (6 => 12 when processed result in 70 + 2 )

This is the expected output with the two arrays above:

```
array ([0] => 72 [1] => 45 [2] => 50 )
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Questions asking for completed code are not on-topic for StackOverflow. You **must** show your efforts and any issues that you encounter while doing that, or your question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following simple solution:

```
$arr1 = [6 => 12, 8 => 9 , 10 => 11];
$arr2 = [6 => 70, 8 => 10, 9 => 35, 10 => 25, 11 => 25, 12 => 2];

$result = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($arr2[$k]) && isset($arr2[$v])) {
        $result[] = $arr2[$k] + $arr2[$v];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 72
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 50
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = Array ( 6 => 12, 8 => 9, 10 => 11 );

$array2 = Array ( 6 => 70, 8 => 10, 9 => 35, 10 => 25, 11 => 25, 12 => 2 );

$newarray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    $newarray[] = $array2[$item] + $array2[$key];
}

var_dump($newarray);
```

Comment: what if `$array2` does not have key or value from `$array1` ?

Comment: Yes there is not much error checking in it.  Just giving a quick example of how it would be done.  Not going all out on it like I am releasing to prod.